# Does MySQLi require close in destruct function?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating a mysqli db object doing the following:

```
class DatabaseQK {
public $db;
public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME, true);

    // if the connection could not be obtained record an error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        log_system_error("Fatal DB Error: ", mysqli_connect_error());
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
}
```

Within the destruct function is the following sufficient to close the connection:

```
public function __destruct() {}
```

or is this needed?

```
public function __destruct() {
    $this->db->close();
}
```

Comment: Better not to use magic functions for that. It's not needed, connection will be destroyed together with class DatabaseQK

Comment: could you elaborate a bit by what you mean with magic functions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Simple `exit` (or `throw ex`) will force php to destroy all objects; and '->close' action might be terminated and behaves unpredictably. `It is recommended that you do not use function names with __ in PHP unless you want some documented magic functionality.`

Comment: As soon as DatabaseQK will be destroyed, it'll automatically destroy all objects inside. Adding something into __destory add troubles for garbage collector

Comment: thank you so much that cleared it up.  I appreciate it.